# Published app but screwed up Android Studio files - How do I make changes to existing app?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am very fresh to Android development, using Android Studio, and managed to publish my first app, displaying a simple webview of my existing online platform. While trying to make changes to the app in Android Studio, I must have screwed with some of the files (deleted old project and created new project). Since then, I have not been able to upload a new bundle/ APK to the play console. Play console would consistently give me an error saying something like "the bundle was not signed with the right key..."

Have tried reading up on this. Concern is now that I may not be able to use the play console account or name of the app anymore because a certain file/ signed code is missing?

Please let me know, in case this should not be the right audience or forum to post this question to, and where it may be more appropriate. Cheers!

Comment: there are lots of ways to break this. your details are kind of vague.  If you lost the key or changed the namespace that would break it this way.  Find the keystore from an old backup and make sure you don't change the package name.  That is the id on the store.

Comment: Sorry for being vague on this. Will try to explain in more detail, as far as I know/ understand. 

I basically deleted the entire previous project folder and created a new one. After I rebuilt the app again, I built a signed APK bundle from and tried to upload this to the google play console again. Google play console gave me an error message, saying the key did not work. I tried renaming the project inside the different project files but also that did not work and probably was not the right approach.

What options do I have now? Can I download the existing app and rebuild it locally?

Comment: Adding that I can't find an old backup from a local android studio project... tried restoring it back then but failed.

Comment: are you on a mac or pc

Comment: Running Android Studio from PC

Comment: Macs have time machine :-(

Comment: But it sounds like you have the project you want; its just signed with the wrong key, Is that part correct?

Comment: I have a published app that I would like to make some changes to (wrong app name and dev icons, etc...). I do not have the local project files anymore and I do not have the keys/ signing key anymore. I only have the online data saved in the google play console. I guess the easiest is, if I delete the existing app in play console and create an entirely new app with the same name, if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need a project with the same package name signed with the same keystore. Any way at all you get that will work.  If none of that is possible, you could try publishing what you have under a new namespace  and key.

it is possible though **not fun** to rename the project package name. I have done it.  [I published a new app with a package name already on the store]

you must back up your keystores
you could put any app with the same namespace and keystore on that store listing.

The way you could have done it was to create an app with the same namespace in a new folder. Sign it with the old key. Done.

Comment: Understood. Problem is though I did not backup this. I have all inside the google play console. Question would now be, how can I replicate the existing app locally from what is stored online.